# Random generator in Javascript with min and max value not working

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I am trying to make an exercise program which generates a random number between a min and a max value. I am facing an issue in the program below. `var2 + min` is not working correctly. If I replace variable min with the actual value, then it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
var var1=Math.random()
var min = prompt("Enter Min value:")
var max = prompt("Enter max value:")
alert("min is "+min+" max is "+max)
var var2=var1*(max-min)
var var3=var2+min
var var4=Math.floor(var3)
alert("var1= "+var1+" var2= "+var2+" var3= "+var3+" Var4 "+var4)
```

Comment: Explain how this is not working. Of course, by now, we have worked out from experience what that is, but it helps others to add those details.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var min = parseInt(prompt("Enter Min value:"), 10);
var max = parseInt(prompt("Enter max value:"), 10);
```

The problem is that these variables contain strings, so the expressions containing `+` are performing string concatenation rather than number addition.

And while you're learning, get in the habit of ending statements with `;`. Javascript is lax about requiring this, but you should be explicit about it -- the rules for when semicolon can be omitted are a bit arcane.

Answer (score 0):

`var1`, `var2`, `var3`, etc. are not good variable names. Don't use them.

Your code isn't working because `prompt` returns a string. `1 - "2"` is `-1`, but `1 + "2"` is `"12"`, as the addition operator is used for string concatenation.

Parse the strings into integers:

```
var min = parseInt(prompt("Enter Min value:"), 10);
```

Comment: I think those variable names were introduced to decompose the original expression in an attempt to debug it :)

Comment: Yes. I added the variables to debug what's happening in each step.

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` returns a `string` so you need to convert `min` and `max` to a `number`:

```
var min = Number(prompt("Enter Min value:"));
var max = Number(prompt("Enter max value:"));
```